# Python class __str__ created and destroyed object

Tags: python, string, class

How to use `__str__` instead of #print?

Here is the code:

```
from itertools import count


class Bug:

  _counter = 0

  def __init__(self):
      Bug._counter += 1
      self.id = Bug._counter
      #print("Obiekt stworzony:", self.id, self._counter)

  def __del__(self):
      Bug._counter -= 1
      self.id = Bug._counter
      #print("Obiekt unicestwiony:", self.id, self._counter)

  def __str__ (self):
      return 


bugs = []
for i in range(100):
    bugs.append(Bug())
    print(bugs[-1])
```

I wanted to print id and number of processes (counter) for `__init__` and `__del__` using with `__str__`.

Comment: Your `__str__(self)` should return a string that's easy to read and shows all members of the class, like `return f"Bug {self.id}"`

Comment: Use of \_\_str\_\_ has been answered. This is a comment about \_\_del\_\_ You should not set self.id to Bug._counter otherwise you could have multiple Bug instances with the same *id*.

Comment: @OldBill I've edited the post to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly then I would suggest this:

```
class Bug:
    _counter = 0 # number of Bug instances
    _ids = [] # list of reusable IDs

    def __init__(self):
        Bug._counter += 1 # increment number of Bug instances
        # reuse previously deleted ID if available otherwise use Bug._counter
        self._id = Bug._counter if len(Bug._ids) == 0 else Bug._ids.pop(0)

    def __del__(self):
        Bug._counter -= 1 # decrement number of Bug instances
        # make this instance's ID available for reuse
        Bug._ids.append(self._id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{Bug._counter=} {self._id=}'

    def __str__ (self):
        return f'Bug count={Bug._counter} ID={self._id}'

# create list with 20 Bugs
bugs = [Bug() for _ in range(20)]
# print last Bug in list
print(bugs[-1])
# delete a bug
del bugs[10]
# print last Bug in list
print(bugs[-1])
# add a new Bug to the list
bugs.append(Bug())
# print last Bug in list
print(bugs[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
Bug count=20 ID=20
Bug count=19 ID=20
Bug count=20 ID=11
```

**Note:**

The Bug with ID == 11 (i.e., subscript 10 in the list) was deleted. When we added a new Bug the ID was reused

Comment: How to print which object was deleted?

Comment: @MalumPhobos How would you suggest printing something that doesn't exist?

Comment: I mean, during terminating object in `__del__` I wanted to print( "Finished", count = , ID = )

Comment: @MalumPhobos OK. So add a call to *print()* in the \_\_del__ override

Comment: How should __del__ override should look like?

Comment: @MalumPhobos I took great care to provide an answer for you and you haven't even looked at the code